# My woocommerce pages and archives don't show "add to cart" below each product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have tried this code I found online and its only showing "read more" under a all the "out of stock" products, not all products. I don't know what to do.

```
// register add to cart action
function woocommerce_add_cart_button () {
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'woocommece_add_cart_button' );
```

Comment: It does seem you have a typo in the action registration: `'woocomme*r*ce_add_cart_button'`, although this might be accidental.

Comment: past here your woocommercce page template in order to help

Comment: which exact template please?

Comment: you will find inside your theme folder  woocommerce/archive-product.php

Comment: I just tried pasting it, it says too long so I can't

Comment: I also spoke to my theme authors, they asked me to edit content-product.php

Comment: How can I paste this please?

Comment: i think we need move to chat  as you can share file there

Comment: ok will do now, but it says I don't have enough reputation to chat

Comment: In general, if a file is too large to show on Stack Overflow, the question wanting to show it is not on-topic on Stack Overflow. Cut the file down to an [mcve], so that it will fit in a question.

Comment: oK now i don't know what to do :( c

Comment: Hello, Ok I've bee able to add this add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 5 ); Just that it's not showing on products in stock, just out of stock products.